# How to select a arbitrary value from list in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Issue : I have a value that is coming from backend and needs to be on the dropdown(It needs to be the default selected value). The dropdown has set of values including that value. But somehow even after specifying that value in the scoep, It is not showing up in the frontend. Here is the code.
**HTML**

```
 <select class="bs-select form-control" ng-model="car.yearOfPurchase " id="year" name="year"  required="">
        <option ng-repeat="year in years" value="year">{{year}}</option>
 </select>
```

**JS**

```
 $scope.years = [];

  for (var i = 2002; i <= parseInt(moment().format("YYYY")); i++) {
        $scope.years.push(i.toString());
    }
    /*Value comign from backend. Mocked in this case.*/
  $scope.car = {
  yearOfPurchase : "2006" 
  };   
  $scope.year = $scope.car.yearOfPurchase;
```

Also, I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/P9kTREp5Q06ASxoPq8nH?p=preview) for the same.

Comment: Can you replace your mock by the way it was really done before please?

Comment: I did not understand by the phrase "replace your mock"??

Comment: You could build your select with ngOptions. Then just set your ngModel with a value from your list and angular will do the rest. Also are how do you get the value from the backend.

Comment: you said : " Mocked in this case."

Comment: by the way : simple mistake : ``<option ng-repeat="year in years" value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <select class="bs-select form-control" ng-model="car.yearOfPurchase" 
    id="year" name="year"  required="" 
    ng-options="year for year in years">
 </select>
```

Be carefull you had a trailing space in your `ng-model`.

I switched to ng-options instead of option with ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Apart from trailing space issue... Why wasn't it working with options tag? Any idea. Just trying to gain up some knowledge here.

Comment: the value attribute was bad. Every options of your select has the value `"year"`(the string). You may try with ng-value="{{year}}". But the best solution is to stick with ng-options.

Comment: Thanks that helped. :D